# Question about store switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, extensions

For a company we are looking for an extension which allows us to show a map of one country. Within this map a site visitor can either enter his zip code or city. Once filled in the nearest locations will be shown. Sort of like Subway does (https://order.subway.com/Stores/Find.aspx#pg1).

Clicking on a location the prices and products belonging to that specific location are shown.

Hope someone can help me figure out if there is an extensions within Magento 1 or 2 for this?

Comment: I don't think there is available extension as per your requirement... If you are developer then any store locator extension is good to start for you. setup each store in magento and based on result from store locator switch them to that store

Comment: Unirgy's Store Locator would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with [FME Advanced Store Locator](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-advance-google-maps-store-locator.html), and it has features like adding stores with their GEO coordinates, searching within defined radius for nearest shop, as well as assigning available products to the stores.

I've used it for search capability when Customer wants to know where a product can be picked up.